# Endpoints with Objectify issue creating Collection

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

To begin, I am developing an app with android studio which uses a backend created using endpoints with Objectify. I have an existing entity containing several fields, one of which is a Collection.
In working on this app I have successfully deployed to localhost and appspot and have been CRUD ing away without any issue.. until now. All of my previous @Index and @Unindex fields can be seen in the datastore viewer in the developer console. BUT when I create a new List field it is no where to be found. I can successfully add and remove all other data types except for collections.

Here is a snippet:

```
@Entity
public class UserData {

    @Id  String userEmail;
    @Index String userName;
    @Unindex String password;
    @Unindex String lastLogin;
    @Unindex List<String> friends = new ArrayList<String>();
```

...Getters and setters

Now when I add

```
@Unindex List<String> newFriends = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and deploy nothing happens and I die a little inside.

In going through what I can see from the generated client library, everything appears to match up with the previous "friends" collection.

A quick thought. The development of this app has been slow and I have gone through a couple versions of Objectify and am currently on v5.1.3. Perhaps when the first collection field was created Objectify handled collections differently. The release Notes mention issues with the @Embed annotation in converting from v4 to v5 but nothing about what I am experiencing.

Another weird note here. When I annotate the "newFriends" collection with @Serialize and deploy.. Voila we have lift off. Once this new @Serialize collection is recognized in the entity I can then go back and change the annotation to @Unindex and all is fine. So really I have solved what I wanted to solve, it just seems that there is a bug crawling around Objectify v5. Or perhaps I am missing something obvious which is why I am inquiring upon the ever so wise community of SO. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I'm a Google Cloud Support Representative. Were you able to solve this issue? If so, could you share the solution for the whole community benefit? If not, I'd like to help you.